# Start multiple selenium test cases using jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I'm a newbie to using jenkins.

I'm using jenkins to build by maven project. After the build process I need to run around 5 selenium2 test cases. Each test case takes around 20 minutes to finish, if I run one test case after the other it takes around 100 minutes complete all the test cases.

I want to know if it is possible to start all the test cases at once so that I can save time.

Currently my pom.xml is as follows -

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <junitArtifactName>junit:junit</junitArtifactName>
          <includes>
                 <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>        

</plugin>
```

Please let me know on how I can do this?

Comment: I can manually start multiple test cases using eclipse. But I want to know how to do this using jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to run tests in parallel from Jenkins is Selenium Grid.

You can find info on the Grid here: http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/

Jenkins plugin here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin